# Interpretation of the coefficient of a dummy variable in a regression with log-transformed outcome

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I want to interpret the models (2) Pool variable. It equals 1 if the house has a pool and 0 if not. The relation between the dependent variable and the Pool variable is a log-linear that means ∆y/y = b1*∆X whereby X is a dummy variable D so the change ∆D can only be 1 or -1 if I am not wrong. So if a house has a pool the price will rise by 7.1% and if house has already a pool and it gets destroyed or something like this the price will decrease by 7.1%. Is this interpretation correct?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you take $\log(y)$ and then run a linear regression using those values, or do you run a generalized linear model with a $\log$ link function?

Comment: Ty Dave. I didnt ran this regression it is from the Stock and Watson "Introduction to Econometrics "book. I think you take ln(y) and then run a regression with the listed variables. So the model is just ln(y) = b0 + b1*ln(size) + b2*Pool + ... + the other dummies.

Comment: Your language is potentially confusing, because it strongly suggests the model is causal.  It is not.  In fact, if a pool were destroyed, that would likely hugely change the value of the house, depending on the circumstances.  The term only estimates the *average difference in log prices* between houses with and without pools, accounting for ("controlling for") all other factors.

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of the coefficient of pool in the second model is: Compared to houses that have no pool, the geometric mean of the price for houses with pools is $100(\exp(0.071) - 1)\% = 7.36\,\%$ higher, all else being held constant. In other words, $\exp(\beta)$ is the ratio of the geometric means of pool/no pool (or generally, current level/reference level of the categorical variable). For more information, see [this page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-do-i-interpret-a-regression-model-when-some-variables-are-log-transformed/).

Comment: I see that this is mathematically more precise. In lecture we used the approximation that ln((y+∆y)/y) is roughly (y+∆y) for small changes. We derived it like this:

ln(y+∆y) = b0 + b1*ln(size) + b2*(Pool+∆Pool) + ... + bi * (other dummy variables) | - ln(y)

=> ln((y+∆y)/y) = b2*∆Pool then using the approximation

=> ∆y/y = b2*∆Pool

I think that is how I get to 7.1% increase if the house has a pool? Isnt it? :D

Comment: @BlankerHans Yes, that's the approximation that Stock and Watson explain and use in their book.

Comment: So regarding this approximation my initial interpretation is (approximatly) correct?

Comment: @BlankerHans As far as I follow Stock and Watson, yes, that seems to be the case, but see whuber's comment to your question.